# How do I parse XML add key to get value with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have a web.config (xml) file from which I need to retrieve a url.  The file looks like:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="urlClickOnce" value="http://www.mysite.launchURL"/>
</appSettings>
```

The script I am using looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function findURL(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: 'Web.config', 
        type:"get",
  dataType:"xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(xml) { 
      var launchURL = $(this).find('appSettings').find('urlClickOnce').attr('value');
      alert(launchURL);
        },
            error:function(){
            alert('err');
            }
        });
    }
```

The alert is displaying but with "Undefined".  How do I access the value in the file?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Yikes!! Don't attempt to query the web.config file directly. I would recommend exposing a service that retrieves app settings and you call that...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Just a guess, but try this:

```
var launchURL = xml.find('appSettings').find('add').attr('value');
```

The information returned via AJAX is stored in a variable called `xml`, per this line:

```
success: function(xml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var launchURL = $(xml).find('appsettings add[key=urlClickOnce]').attr('value');
```